# html inside email

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I am sending email through gmail, i want to send some html content, is it possible to do if yes then how??

Comment: As turns out in the comments of my deleted answer, Praveen does **not** want to send a mail programmatically, but just to enter HTML directly in the Gmail editor. This has nothing to do with programming. I requested a move to Superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with BalusC, but here's an answer anyways cause I'm feeling nice today.

Upload the media online, either to tinypic.com or use the URL where the image/video/animation is stored.

Goto to pages.google.com and "add" the image to ANY webpage (can be a dummy one that is setup just for this purpose, you dont need to actually publish the page). MAKE sure you don't browse to the content that is stored on your computers harddrive. It MUST be stored somewhere accessible online.

When it gets added to the page in the WYSIWYG editor, right click it and "copy" the object.

Goto gmail and paste it into the email.

courtesy of Paul Di Biase